# Parse.com Class design

Tags: parse-platform, schema

Read everything relating to this I can on SO. I am trying to develop a recipe app using Parse.com. Starting to struggle with the design of the classes however. What I need is that ability to store a recipe name, the ingredient, and their quantities.

Currently I have this:

Recipes

- Name(string)
- Description(string)
- Ingredients(Relation to Ingredients class)

Ingredients

- Manufacturer(string)
- Name(string)

Where I am stuck is how to save a quantity for each ingredient for each recipe. From what I have seen it seems the best way to do this would be to make a third class. Let's say

RecipeDetail

- Recipe(Relation to Recipes class)
- Ingredient(Relation to Ingredients class)
- Quantity

This seems like a very obtuse way to handle the task but I haven't found a better way. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a third class is appropriate (other options mean creating an object with a reference and a class is a better way of doing that). I'd use a relationship from the Recipe class to the Detail class and a pointer from Detail to Ingredient. The 'relationship' from Recipe to Detail could be implemented as an array of pointers as it's unlikely that the list of ingredients will be particularly long or that you'll need to filter it.

Detail objects need to be deleted when removed from a Recipe. Ingredients aren't (or are only deleted when there are no Detail items pointing to them).

Note that you can use `includeKey` to shortcut some processing when you download the Detail items for a Recipe (the pointer allows you to shortcut and include the pointed to Ingredient details).

Comment: I suppose I'm misunderstanding little. If the Recipe class has a column that is a relation to the Details class, how would you establish that relationship?

Comment: How are you planning to populate? User generated? As they enter ingredients you search for existing and create new, create Details items pointing to them and add the details to the Recipe relationship.

Comment: I've made considerable progress on this and my understanding of Parse. I am to a point now that I am wondering why it is better to use a Relation from Recipes to Details instead of an Array.

Comment: You certainly could use an array of pointers, this approach also means you could use `includeKey` to trim the request count (it doesn't work for relationships and re-reading my answer that is not clear...). It's unlikely that the ingredient list will be big enough that performance is an issue with an array so if you like that approach better it's good.

Comment: Well that idea may not work out. For whatever reason the includes don't actually fetch any data. I am back to my original API request count if I have to manually fetch each included object. It's strange I am using includes elsewhere and they retrieve all data.

Comment: Array was created progmattically by using recipe.add("details",ingredients); where ingredients is an array list of parse objects just created and saved before. I messed around with the query but building a blank query of just getQuery("Recipes") and adding query.include("details"). I tried nested includes as well and they return nothing too. Just the original Recipe objects.

Comment: Figured out the issue. Because I was doing .add(ingredients) if was putting an array in an array so the detail field had two sets of  [] surrounding it. Broke the whole operation.